# php file is respond to Android post method as forbidden

Tags: php, android, androidhttpclient

And I try to connect my android webApplication with a php file which is placed in wamp server prg4 folder.

I run this app and check the packets gone thrugh the network via the wireshark. Post message is pass successfully. but the relavant response message says 403 forbidden.

I also make another html site to check my php file and it works good.

Due to less experience in asyntask activity i didn't add any notification/message to show when message received.

NOTE:-My wamp server running on port 81 and I simulated on genymotion emulator.

```
package com.example.autocomplete.post2;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
InputStream inputStream;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new LongOperation().execute("");
        }
    });
}

public void go(){
    HttpClient htcl=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost htpost=new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:81/");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "hi"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234"));
    try {
        htpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpResponse response=null;
    try {
        response = htcl.execute(htpost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("Response",response.toString());
}
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient htcl=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost htpost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.56.1:81/prg4/upload.php");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", "hi"));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234"));
        try {
            htpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpResponse response=null;
        try {
            response = htcl.execute(htpost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
        // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
}
```

Here is the my phpcode..

```
$q=$_POST["q"];
if ($q=="hi"){
$fp = fopen("a.txt","w");
fputs($fp,"hiiiiiiiiiiiii");//Rewrite updated data into txt file
}
else{
$fp = fopen("a.txt","w");
fputs($fp,"lllllllll");//Rewrite updated data into txt file
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three common causes for this error. Here they are listed from most likely to least likely.

**Empty html directory**

Make sure that your website content has been uploaded to the correct directory on your server. Remember to replace example.com with your own domain name.

Grid: /domains/example.com/html/
This is the path you will use for FTP. However, the full path to your website content is /home/00000/domains/example.com/html/. The 00000 is your site number. See this article for details.
If this folder does not exist, feel free to create it.

**No index page**

The home page for your website must be called index.php or index.html.

To resolve this error, upload an index page to your html directory.

If you already have a home page called something else - home.html for example - you have a couple of options:

Rename your home page to index.html or index.php.
Set up a redirect on the index page to your real home page. See How do I redirect my site using a .htaccess file? for details.
Set a different default home page in your .htaccess file. Javascript Kit has a good example.
If you don't want a single page to display, but instead want to show a list of files in that directory, see Making directories browsable, solving 403 errors.

**Permissions and ownership errors**

A 403 Forbidden error can also be caused by incorrect ownership or permissions on your web content files and folders.

Permissions
Rule of thumb for correct permissions:
Folders: 755
Static Content: 644
Dynamic Content: 700
Please see File Permissions for a complete discussion of permissions and security.

*I think there is some file read/write permission issue .Please remove the file access code and try*

Answer (score 0):

check if your hosting allow remote control of the Database